# Car taken out in a dealer

Tags: car

I purchased a car from a dealer. The car is for my use. I have my father as the first signatory. I have co-signed for him. I am making the payment for this car. Can I remove my dad's name and have my husband added as first to the title in the Car and I continue as a second person?

My dad also took away from my car the registration papers what can I do in this case???

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're asking about? And what country are you in?

Comment: If your father is the first signatory on the loan papers and you are merely co-signing the loan agreement (though you are making all the payments), then he is likely the owner (maybe even the sole owner) of the car for legal purposes. It is unlikely that you can make the desired change on the car title.

Comment: If you don't have the registration papers in your car, that's also a big deal that you should get taken care of ASAP. God forbid you get pulled over and can't produce that documentation...

Answer (score 4):

I bought my first car the same way.  Both my and my fathers names were on the title.  When it was time to sell it both our signatures would have been needed at the dealer.  To simplify the logistics the first thing we did was to transfer the title to my name only.  Both our signatures were required for this as well.

If you're still paying the loan, the title itself is almost certainly in the banks possession; and any change will require their approval as well.  They'll need your fathers signature too.  If your father co-signed because his better credit convinced the bank to issue a lower interest loan, they'd probably insist on a new loan being created in your name only at a higher rate if they're willing to lend to you at all.

Unfortunately, without his cooperation you're unlikely to be able to get full ownership of the car without involving the court system.  Even if they are willing to do so (I have no idea how likely this is); suing your father isn't so much burning as nuking your bridges behind you.